# How to execute the second event after the first event is triggered

Tags: angular, rxjs

Is there a way to execute the second event after the first event is triggered?

In the below example I would like to use scroll event after touchmove event is called.

```js
fromEvent(window, 'touchmove').pipe(
  tap(() => this.scroll$.next(false),
    debounceTime(100)
).subscribe(() => {
  this.scroll$.next(true);
})
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific. Your `scroll` variable seems just to be a boolean. By `I would like to use scroll event` what do you exactly mean? Also I can only see one event in your code example `fromEvent( window, 'touchmove')`.

Comment: As you just opened a bounty on this question - is there something missing in my answer? As I mentioned your question has a lack of information. Any sign of communication and feedback would be great to be able to help you.

Answer (score 5):

If your `scroll$` `Observable` can depend on other observables and don't has to be a `Subject` you can let it directly depend from the `fromEvent` `Observable`.

```js
private sroll$ = fromEvent$(window, 'touchmove').pipe(
  switchMapTo(
    merge(
      of(false),
      timer(100).pipe(mapTo(true))
    )
  )
)
```

The `scroll$` Observable gets triggered by the `fromEvent$(window, 'touchmove')` Observable. Then we `switchMapTo` to a combination operator `merge`:

- This way we can instantly return a `false` value by creating a Observable with only that value (`of(false)`).
- Furthermore we can start a `timer` that fires `true` 100 ms after.

Comment: or like this
merge(of(false),
of(true).pipe(delay(100)))

Answer (score 0):

In case you really can't use `touchstart` and `touchend` the only way is to use `debounceTime` pipe

```
const mousemove$ = fromEvent(document, 'mousemove');
    mousemove$
      .pipe(
        first(),
        switchMap(() => mousemove$),
        tap(() => this.scroll$.next(false)),
        debounceTime(1000)
      )
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.scroll$.next(true);
      });
```

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vyujvu?file=src/app/app.component.ts)